# method completes but data is not inserted into SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, localdb

i have a method which should save user details to a local database on Visual Studio, the method below is in question

```
   private void btnSaveDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var IssueDate = this.dtpIssueDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')";
        //var ExipryDate =this.dtpExpiryDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')";
        var mainMenu = new frmMainMenu();
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        sc.ConnectionString = (Properties.Settings.Default.BioEngineering);
        sc.Open();
        com.Connection = sc;


        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", this.txtFirstName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", this.txtLastName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", this.txtCompany.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityLevel", this.cboSecurityLevel.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IssueDate", this.dtpIssueDate.Value);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpiryDate", this.dtpExpiryDate.Value);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardID", this.cboCardID.Text);

        com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (Forename, Surname, Company, SecurityLevel, IssueDate, ExpiryDate, CardID) VALUES (@Forename,@Surname,@Company,@SecurityLevel,@IssueDate,@ExpiryDate,@CardID)";
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sc.Close();
        this.Hide();
        mainMenu.Show();
    }
```

I get no errors and when i add a breakpoint at com.ExecuteNonQuery it appears to have the correct data....any ideas? i first thought it was the connection string but seen other sites with similar formats so dont think its it

Comment: Is this insert query works in your database manager?

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Server Profiler, to find out whether the query actually runs against your database?

Comment: Make sure to have the `BioEngineering` setting configured as a connection string. You can then use the built-in dialog to configure the connection string. This is to make sure you always have correct connection strings.

Comment: @YannickMeeus query does not run

Comment: Wrap your method inside `try-catch` and check if the `ExecuteNonQuery()` throws an exception. I guess there's something wrong with the `parameters` or `connection string`

Comment: Hi all i get the following error now System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at BioengineeringResearchLtd.frmAddMember.btnSaveDetails_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `CommandText` property before adding any parameters to your command. Simply stating, put this :

```
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (Forename, Surname, Company, SecurityLevel, IssueDate, ExpiryDate, CardID) VALUES (@Forename,@Surname,@Company,@SecurityLevel,@IssueDate,@ExpiryDate,@CardID)";
```

before this :

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", this.txtFirstName.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", this.txtLastName.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", this.txtCompany.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityLevel", this.cboSecurityLevel.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IssueDate", this.dtpIssueDate.Value);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpiryDate", this.dtpExpiryDate.Value);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardID", this.cboCardID.Text);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: still no success unfortunately :(